# Is is possible to use kpfonts in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I would like to use kpfonts in matplotlib.

I am loading the kpfonts package to the latex preamble in matplotlib through

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({
    "font.family": "serif",
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preamble': [
        r'\usepackage{amsmath}',
        r'\usepackage{amssymb}',
        r"\usepackage{siunitx}",
        r"\usepackage{kpfonts}",
     ]
})
```

In pdfLaTeX, loading \usepackage{kpfonts} is sufficient to use that font.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to run your code I get the error message

```
[...]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
[...]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts/kpfonts.sty

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.94 ...textcomp\RequirePackage[full]{textcomp}\fi
                                                  \fi
```

Assuming this is the same error you get, this can be fixed by adding the `notextcomp` option:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({
    "font.family": "serif",
    "text.usetex": True,
    'text.latex.preamble': [
        r'\usepackage{amsmath}',
        r'\usepackage{amssymb}',
        r"\usepackage{siunitx}",
        r"\usepackage[notextcomp]{kpfonts}",
     ]
})
```

BTW, in general it would be good to mention the kind of result you get from your attempts. In this case I can only guess that you got this error message.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks @ralf
You were correct about the error message. And thank you for the advise